# TWA: showing url header in playstore installs

Tags: android, google-play-console, trusted-web-activity

I created my app using TWA. While installing the apk directly it was working fine. No URL header was there, the website loaded without any header.
but after I released it in playstore when people download the app from playstore there is a URL header in my app.
My .well-known/assetlinks.json is configured in my host. any fix?

Answer (score 2):

If you opted into [Play App signing](https://play.google.com/console/about/keymanagement/), Play will generate a different key to sign the APK downloaded to users devices.

You can get the SHA-256 from Play in using one of the approaches below:

- Using the [Asset Links Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.conn.assetlinkstool)

  1. Install the Asset Link Tool from Google Play.
  2. Download your app from the Google Play.
  3. Launch the Asset Links Tool.
  4. When the app launches, you'll be given a list of all applications installed on your device by applicationId. Filter the list by the applicationId you chose earlier and click on that entry.
  5. You'll see a page listing your app's signature and with a generated Digital Asset Link. Click on the Copy or Share buttons at the bottom to export it however you like (e.g., save to Google Keep, email it to yourself).
- or, from the [Google Play console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/):

  1. Open the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
  2. Select your app.
  3. Choose Release management and then App signing from the panel on the left.
  4. Copy the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint from under the App signing certificate section.
  5. Use this value in your Digital Asset Link file.

You can then either replace the fingerprint in your `assetlinks.json` or keep both fingerprints (which makes testing the build locally easier). An assetlinks file with both fingerprints looks like the following:

```json
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.appspot.pwa_directory",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
      "FA:2A:03:CB:38:9C:F3:BE:28:E3:CA:7F:DA:2E:FA:4F:4A:96:F3:BC:45:2C:08:A2:16:A1:5D:FD:AB:46:BC:9D"
    ]
  }
},{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.appspot.pwa_directory",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
      "4F:FF:49:FF:C6:1A:22:E3:BB:6F:E6:E1:E6:5B:40:17:55:C0:A9:F9:02:D9:BF:28:38:0B:AE:A7:46:A0:61:8C"
    ]
  }
}]
```

You can read more about both subjects on the [quick start guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/quick-start/) in the official docs.